# Can we build Mobile app with bubble.is that has support for video calling from the app?

Tags: android, mobile-application

I am exploring the possibility to make mobile apps using bubble.is and we intend to have a feature where the app user can do a video call and talk with us.
Do you think we can use some exisiting thing to integrate with bubble.is app to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [GoNative](https://gonative.io/) to make a mobile app using bubble.is and [Gruveo](https://www.gruveo.com/) or a similar service to do this.

The positioning with Gruveo is a bit difficult if you want your app to be responsive (tablets? desktop?) but its doable.